# err: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Tags: vagrant, puppet

Everytime I run `puppet agent -t` I get this error

```
err: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled
```

I just added vagrant folder, did init and my vagrant file

```
 config.vm.box = "hashicorp/precise64"

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh"
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 80, host: 436
```

and bootstrap.sh file

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

apt-get update
apt-get install -y apache2
if ! [ -L /var/www ]; then
  rm -rf /var/www
  ln -fs /vagrant /var/www
fi
```

after setting up all this I ran vagrant up command, then did vagrant ssh. Till this everything worked fine.

Then I started to run some puppet commands from their [doc](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.3/reference/quick_start_user_group.html). Whenever I run `puppet agent -t` I get above mentioned error. How can I solve this?

I am using linux mint and virtual box, vagrant and puppet.

Answer (score 2):

Puppet default search 'puppet' A record in search zone (/etc/resolv.conf):
If your zone is: internal.mydomain.com => puppet will be searching 'puppet.internal.mydomain.com' machine in your network.

You can specify custom server with in parameter:

```
puppet agent --no-daemonize --debug --onetime --server yourcustomserver.internal.mydomain.com
```

And please check your /etc/hosts file so:

```
%
127.0.0.1                               localhost  ip4-localhost  ip4-loopback
::1                                     localhost  ip6-localhost  ip6-loopback
[IP]                                    [FQDN]     [HOSTNAME]

fe00::0                                 ip6-localnet
ff00::0                                 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1                                 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2                                 ip6-allrouters
```

Comment: I still get this error Info: Creating a new SSL key for puppet.example.com
Debug: Creating new connection for https://puppet.example.com.internal.mydomain.com:8140
Error: Could not request certificate: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known
Exiting; failed to retrieve certificate and waitforcert is disabled

Comment: Yes. Agent couldn't connect to master. If you will ping to master, what you see ?

Comment: If I ping 'ping 127.0.0.1' I get proper response '64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.030 ms
'

Comment: Ok. And if you will "ping puppet" ?

Comment: I get output 'ping: unknown host puppet
'

Comment: Ok. So, agent cannot found your master. Have you got puppet master or only an agent ?